# CouchDB Java libraries get downloaded by Maven, but don't not recognised by IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, couchdb, pom.xml

I use *Maven* and *CouchDB*. I put a *CouchDB* java library dependency in `pom.xml` and recompile using maven. I see that files get downloaded and the compilation succeeds with no error, but IntelliJ that I use can't find this library or its classes.

I used *ektorp*, *couchdb4j* and *jcouchdb*, but had the same problem. Any help?

Comment: What is the runtime error? Or is this compile time error?

Comment: I assume that's a typo for *IntelliJ*. In which case, does this question boil down to getting IntelliJ to recognise a new library? I'm not familiar with IntelliJ, but a brief Google suggests you may wish to run `mvn idea:idea` to refresh its notion of the dependencies. Certainly that's what I would do with Eclipse (`mvn eclipse:eclipse`).

Comment: @DuncanJones No don't use the `mvn idea:idea` plugin. It is old and obsolete: [Maven Idea Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/). Last update is from 2008. Nowadays just open project and point to `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have opened the project by using `[File]->[Open Project...]` and then point on the `pom.xml` then IntelliJ will keep track on changes/updates in the pom.

Do not use the [`maven-idea-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/) since it is obsolete, last changes are from 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into a working example and compare it with yours https://github.com/softberries/woodstoxex (couchdb branch), for pure MFN project you can create an IntelliJ project using 'from existing model' option and selecting maven from the list